# Finding my peers network addresses bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin, peer, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I'm trying to get all of the current ip addresses for the peers connected to my node. A bit similar to what [bitnodes](https://bitnodes.earn.com) is doing. I can't figure out if there is an API call to be sent from the bitcoind client which returns a list of addresses.

I've read about the `getaddr` message but have no idea how to send it to the node's peers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getpeerinfo command, Returns data about each connected node.